# Convert Oracle stored procedure to Hive or Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stored-procedures, hive, user-defined-functions

I have written stored procedures in Oracle. Is there any way I can implement the same functionalities of that stored procedure in Hive or Spark.

As in Oracle stored procedures, we have cursors and we can call one procedure inside the other procedure with plenty of other operations too.

Please suggest if that’s possible in Hive or if there is some other way around. I searched online and it seems Hive version 2 provides an option to work with stored procedures.

But what could be the solution for the older versions?

I'm new to Hive and Spark so any guidance or suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a plain `java.sql.Connection`, `CallableStatement`, etc. to call your Stored Procedure from Spark.

e.g.

```
 protected ResultSet fetchDataFromJdbc(String storedProc) {
   Connection connection;
   CallableStatement statement;

   try {
     Class.forName("my.db.Driver");

     connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url","user","pass");

     statement = connection.prepareCall(storedProc);
     statement.registerOutParameter(1, "outValue");
     statement.executeQuery();

     return (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1);
   } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         log.error(e.getMessage());
   }

 throw new IllegalStateException("Results should have returned.");
}
```